# dd-wrt and squid proxy

Tags: squid, dd-wrt

I am now using linksys router with dd-wrt firmware & squid proxy from off-site (VPN) for anonymity. The problem is i have to configure proxy setting in my browser to access that proxy.
What i would like to do is to get all my traffic pass through the router via squid proxy without configuring any setting in browser.
I can't use openvpn due to port blockage in my country. My current squid proxy listen to port 443.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is a transparent proxy configuration given at their [website](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Transparent_web_proxy). It works also for non-squid based proxy software.